# How to nest role attributes in HTML?

Tags: html, accessibility

I need to nest some elements where two elements have a role attribute.
Is it possible that the inner elements are also read out?

My code:

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
    <div class="panel-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="icons">
                    <div class="icon" role="link" aria-label="Go to new page" [routerLink]="['/newpage']"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="description" role="text" aria-label="One plus one is two">
                    <div class="description-text">
                        1 + 1 = 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I simplified the code. So I have to say that the role="tab" has to be there.

Does someone know how I could achieve this?

It would be also okay, if the second text is on the role="tab" element

Comment: Can you explain why you use a `div` with `role="link"` if you can use the `a` element, which natively has the link role?

Comment: Same with div with role of text. Why not a paragraph element?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @ChristopheStrobbe and @stringy!
I could change these things, but I still can't click on the icon, because the role="tab" div is marked in voice over mode...

Comment: Is this usecase like a link inside a link? The whole element (tab headlien) is ment to open/close the tab and then there is the icon as another link element? Thats a bit confusing, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> I still can't click on the icon, because the role="tab" div is marked in voice over mode..

You don't have a `tabindex=0` attribute on your link. If you have problem clicking on this link, then you have to set this attribute in order for the link to be pressable.

There's no problem with having a `role=tab` element which encloses a `role=link`  element. It's quite common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added tabindex=0, but it's still not clickable in voice over mode... (In normal mode I can click on it)

Comment: @chocolatecake Can you confirm me that without the `role=tab` it works as expected?